# PHP, регулярные выражения. Извлечение строк между тегами.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте! Моя задача получить одну таблицу (от < table..... до < /table>) из большой каши на html-е. Эта таблица отличается от массы остальных тем, что имеет в открывающем теге следующую запись:

```
class="table01"
```

Исходя из этого составляю соответствующий шаблон:

```
'/<table .* class="table01" .*>[\S\s]*<\/table>/Uix'
```

И в итоге получаю нуль. Причем хоть так, хоть так:

```
$pregTable = '/<table .*? class="table01" .*?>[\S\s]*?<\/table>/ix';
```

Вот сам код:

```
$file = file_get_contents('test.html');
$pregTable = '/<table .* class="table01" .*>[\S\s]*<\/table>/Uix';
$arrTable = array();
preg_match_all($pregTable, $file, $arrTable, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($arrTable);
```

Перепробовал кучу разных вариантов, мучаюсь целый день, ничего не выходит. Получаю либо текст от начала нужной таблицы до закрытия последней - если не использую ? или модификатор U, либо нуль - если с ними. Что я тут делаю не правильно?

Comment: Советую в помощь http://realcode.ru/regexptester/ и http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Тема! :) Спасибо большое! Затестил свои шаблоны по ссылкам - все ок - на деле - ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимание, правильный ответ!

```
preg_last_error()
```

вывел мне код ошибки - 2, это означает

```
2 - PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR - Лимит обратных ссылок исчерпан
```

Всего навсего нужно было раскоментировать

```
pcre.backtrack_limit=100000
```

в php.ini, и увеличить этот лимит, тк в моем злосчастном файле аж 146428 символов!
Теперь все ок, и простое выражение:

```
'/<table .* class="table01" [\S\s]* <\/table>/Uix'
```

замечательно работает! Надеюсь информация окажется полезной. Еще раз всем спасибо за содействие :)

Comment: И еще добавлю.. Viktor вчера советовал вот эти две ссылки  
http://realcode.ru/regexptester/  
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/  
Там веб-морда для разработки паттернов в реальном времени.  
Вот еще такой скрипт:  
http://danechka.com/tester.php  
Тут по крайней мере не глючит, да и модификаторы можно любые самому добавлять! Написал мой друг! В общем, рекомендую :)

Comment: я ж эту функцию и посоветовал для отладки

Comment: Вот именно! Я про нее знал, но не придал значения :)

Answer (score 10):

Самый простой и самый эффективный способ в данном случае - это распарсить HTML при помощи [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) и получить таблицу через XPath:

```
$text = <<< EOS
<body>
<table class="table01">
    <tr><th>First table</th></tr>
    <tr><td><table><tr><th>Inner <table><tr><th></th></tr></table> table</th></tr></table></td></tr>
    <tr><td><table><tr><th>Second inner table</th></tr></table></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr><td>Second outer table</th></tr>
</table>
</body>
EOS;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//table[@class="table01"]');
var_dump($dom->saveXML($nodes->item(0)));
```

Однако, при желании можно решить данную задачу и при помощи регулярного выражения. Проблема со вложенными таблицами в данном случае решается при помощи [рекурсивных выражений](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php):

```
$class = 'table01';

// Любой символ, с которого не начинается тег <table>
$any = "(?: [^<] | <(?!/?table\b) )";

// Открытый и закрытий теги <table>, между которыми любое количество символов $any,
// либо подставить рекурсивно подшаблон #2 (шаблон #1 - это кавычка, см. далее)
$inner = "(<table[^>]*> (?> $any | (?2) )+? </table>)";

// Тоже самое, что и $inner, но с дополнительным атрибутом у тега <table>
// Модификатор 's' в данном случае не нужен, т.к. мы не используем мета-символ '.'
// А модификатор 'U' не нужен, поскольку мы оперируем только ascii символами
$pattern = "~<table\b[^>]*\bclass=(\"|')?$class\\1[^>]*> (?> $any | $inner )+ </table>~xi";

preg_match($pattern, $text, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

Comment: Доработал регулярку. А то вчера в час ночи немного поспешил с ней :)

Answer (score 3):

Как бы вам объяснить ...
есть два варианта:

первый:

```
preg_match('~<table.*?>(.*?)</table>~is', $content, $m );
```

и второй:

```
preg_match('~<table.*?>(.*)</table>~is', $content, $m );
```

Разница только в "?"

первый не подойдёт если внутри таблицы есть еще одна, вложенная таблица.

А второй вариант не подойдёт когда на странице есть 2 таблици паралельно.

**Первое правило парсинга гласит: перед тем как смотреть что на выходе, посмотри что на входе** (это моё правило, вывел его после таких долгих мучений :) )

Поэтому посмотрите что вы таки парсить пытаетесь, скорее всего вы получаете не ту страницу что ожидаете, либо вообще пустой текст ( например запрещены исходящие запросы )

Comment: Зачем два варианта? Изложенные вами инструкции мне ясны, но я же написал, что таблица одна, и от других отличается только наличием class="table01". Вложенных таблиц не имеет. Должен работать шаблон, который предложил Павел Владимиров - "|<table.*class=\"table01\".*</table>|sU"... Но он почему-то не работает!

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж завели речь о DOM парсерах:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');
$ret = $html->find('table[class=table01]');
```

Answer (score 1):

должно работать с модификаторами "s" и "U"

```
preg_match("|<table.*class=\"table01\".*</table>|sU",$text,$match);
```

Comment: Прекрасно понимаю, что означает и как работает ваш шаблон, но как ни странно он все равно возвращает пустой массив.

Comment: выложите пример HTML текста или ссылку на ваш файл, который вы разбираете. скорей всего ошибка в HTML.

Comment: Позже выложу.. Там, дело в том, что если искать теги по отдельности (например "|<table.*class=\"table01\">|", или "|</table>|" - то все нормально находится. Сам хтмл-документ очень большой. Может быть есть какие ограничения по объему? Ума не приложу.

Comment: большие регулярки я обычно так проверяю: 
обрезаю регулярку, например пополам. если она выдает то, что нужно, дописываю еще часть и так далее. так можно определить место, на котором она неправильно работает.
а что касается большого документа, то про ограничения размеров ничего сказать не могу. в официальной документации не нашел такого ограничения.

Comment: Регулярка не большая. Большой  - html. Вашим методом постепенного наращивания регулярки я пробовал делать еще до того как создал здесь вопрос.. Ошибка возникает именно в тот момент, когда я начинаю регулировать жадность квантификаторов знаком вопроса, или модификатором U.

Comment: попробуйте отладить с помощью функции preg_last_error 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php

Answer (score 1):

Задача, прямо скажу, нетривиальная и простой регуляркой ее не решить. Есть два типа регулярных выражений: ленивые и жадные. Ленивое выражение может вытащить вам таблицу внутри нужной и первый кусок нужной таблицы, что явно мало. Жадное может вытащить нужную таблицу и еще полстраницы кода, что тоже неприемлимо. Напрашиваются два выхода:
 1. использовать php-парсер, пропускать код через него и искать нужную таблицу методами класса
 2. написать свою функцию, вытаскивающую все закрывающие и открывающие теги и запоминающую их вхождения. А потом надо будет пройтись по запомненным значениям и, имея начало и конец таблицы, вытащить все, что между.
Пока только такие идеи.

Comment: Почему не решить? Извлечь из "большого текстовика" все, от < table .... до ...</ table> я думаю, грамотнее всего, будет именно с помощью регулярных выражений.

Comment: Если вы уверены, что у вас на странице только одна эта таблица, то почему бы и нет. Но если у вас на странице что-то такое: <table><table></table></table><table></table>, то "малой кровью" уже не отделаетесь.

Comment: Да, у меня html именно такой запутанный, как вы написали! Но, если вы внимательно прочитаете вопрос, то увидите, что нужная таблица имеет class="table01", и, добавлю - вложенных таблиц не имеет. Задача, казалось бы, куда проще! \'/<table .*? class="table01" [\S\s]*?<\/table>/\' - т.е. берем все, где встречается <table и за ним, через неизвестное количество символов (айди и прочие, неуникальные, параметры таблицы) есть class="table01", затем - берем все печатные символы и переносы строк (пробелы) до первого закрывающего </table>. Но ни это условие, никакие похожие не работают =(((

Comment: Ну, раз так, то $pattern = '/<table[^>]+class="table01"[^>]+>(.+?)<\/table>/';

Comment: я вижу такие проблемы, почему у вас не работает регулярка:
- неверная регулярка (проверено, значит дело не в ней)
- ошибка в HTML. может быть там < /table > или еще что-то подобное написано (надо более внимательно просмотреть исходный HTML)
- ваш HTML обрезается при считывании из файла (попробовать вывести его в другой файл или на экран и посмотреть)
- регулярка обрабатывается с ошибкой (посмотреть, что возвращает функция preg_last_error)
без отладки на конкретной задаче ничего нельзя сказать.

Comment: Все эти моменты я проработал... Все, кроме вывода preg_last_error(). Как раз эта функция и помогла мне найти решение!

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за помощь и за советы! Хоть вопрос и не решил, новых знаний получил не мало.
В общем разрешил я свою проблему весьма радикальным способом:

```
function getStrBetween($string, $from, $to)
{

    $prepared =
    substr //обрезаем лишнее сначала
        (
            $string,
            stripos //вычисляем количество лишних символов сначала файла
            (
                $string,
                $from
            )
        );

        $returned =
        substr //обрезаем лишнее в конце
        (
            $prepared,
            0,
            (
                stripos
                (
                    $prepared,
                    $to
                ) - strlen($prepared) + strlen($to)
            )
        );

    return $returned;

}
```

Желаемого результата добился, но вопрос остается открытым, для тех, кому интересно почему-же тут не сработала регулярка.

Comment: Так а что preg_last_error() выдал что-нибудь или нет?

Comment: Только что попробовал! с шаблоном:

    '/<table .* class="table" [\S\s]* <\/table>/Uix'

preg_last_error() выводит 2

Comment: И вот, что это означает:
2 - PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR - Лимит обратных ссылок исчерпан
А что это означает? о_О

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit
В первом же комментарии утверждают, что лимит в 100m (по дефолту 100к) без проблем отрабатывает на нетбуке. Попробуйте поиграться с этим значением.