# Регулярное выражение для получения содержимого между тегами tr

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здраствуйте, подскажите регулярное выражение для получения содержимого между тегами `tr` `/tr`, с помощью `preg_match_all`, между ними могут встречаться все символы, кроме вышеуказаных тегов, символов неопределенное количество (от 1 до бесконечности).

И если это возможно, то и в случае если между ними могут быть размещены таблицы (т.е. могут существовать теги `tr` `/tr`).

Comment: Для вложенных tr сложнее, вы должны знать количество вложений, чтобы написать точно, а так вряд ли регулярка сама догадается, где ей остановиться/что захватывать.

Comment: Можете либо чётко вложенную регулярку написать, но тогда она будет ровно столько вложений читать сколько вы сделаете. Либо можно в массив сохранять значение с каждой вложенности и в итоге вынимать из массива нужное вложение.

Comment: Можно подробней по поводу знать количество? ) Ровно 2 раза открыв \\ закрывается между необходимыми, т.е. 

    [tr] [tr] [\\tr] [tr] [\\tr] [\\tr]

Comment: Вот решение но оно капец какое прямое в лоб.  

    <tr>.*<\\tr>.*<tr>.*<\\tr>(?=<\\tr>)<\\tr>

Эта рега найдёт вам всё включая tr крайние. А вообще очень красивое решение было описано в книге регулярных выражений (Регулярные выражения, 2-е изд. Дж. Фридл). Там было изящное решение, к сожалению, задача очень редкая и я не запомнил того решения.

Comment: Большое спасибо за указание на книжку, будем почитать...

С регулярками поковыряюсь еще вечерком, как только с работой разгребусь, тогда и отпишусь, что и как сработало. )

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP, регулярные выражения. Извлечение строк между тегами.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15075/php-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP, регулярные выражения. Извлечение строк между тегами.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15075/php-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#15133)

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, не силён в этом, но мне кажется как-то так...

```
if (preg_match('|<tr.*?>(.*)</tr>|sei', $str, $arr)) $tr = $arr[1];
else $tr='';
```

Comment: Не сочтите за придирство, но знак ? можно после .* и не ставить, так как сама звёздочка говорит о том что может и не быть ничего.

Comment: Если не сложно, поясните несколько символов в выражении, в частности "|"(вроде начало "/"), далее "sei" что сие означает? И укажите на ошибку в такой записи, ибо она не работала....

`"/\<tr\>.{1,}\<\/tr\>/"` хотя означает практически то же, что и ваша
и сия запись также корректно не работала
"/\<tr\>[^tr]{1,}\<\/tr\>/"`

Обе игнорировали N-ное количество `<\tr>` зависимо от верхней граници размера.

Comment: /<tr>[^tr]{1,}</tr>/ 

тут конструкция неверная, в таких скобках [] учитываются символы, а не слова целиком. ".{1,}" можно и так, только это не одно и тоже со звёздочкой, это одно и тоже с плюсом, хотя бы одно должно быть, но и так не рекомендуется, ведь спецом были * + придуманы, чтобы так не извращались. sei - это ключи (поиск не взирая на энтеры, не смотря на регистр букв), но увы не PHP'шник, точного значения сказать не могу, гуглите.

Comment: Хммм, подскажите тогда отрицание слова, если это отрицание символа(ов); регулярные выражения использовал пару лет назад и очень мало, и ничего о них практически не помню... исходя из того, что накопал побыстрому в интернетах и исходил, когда составлял. )