# Как найти элемент DOM с учетом вложенности по значению атрибута на php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть шаблон вида:

```
<section name="myname1">
     ...
     <div name="myname2">
          ... 
          <p name="myname3">
               ...
          </p>
          ...
     </div>
     ...
</section>
<div name="myname4">
     ...
     <div name="myname5">
          ... 
     </div>
     ...
</div>
```

Задача в том чтобы найти все элементы DOM у которых есть атрибут «name» верхнего уровня со всеми вложенными в него элементами. При этом атрибут может содержать текст на кириллице, собственно так же как и вложенные конструкции в него.

Библиотеки я использовать не могу (есть требование заказчика исключить зависимости).

**Первый подход к снаряду был такой:**

/<\s*([a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*\bname\s*=\s*\"([^\"]*)[^>]*>(?>(?:[^<]|<(?!\s*/?\1\s*\b))|(<\s*\1[^>]*>(?>(?:[^<]|<(?!\s*/?\s*\1\s*\b))|(?3))+?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>))*</\1>/is

Это работает до тех пор, пока вложенность тега

```
<section name="myname1"> ... </section>
```

не вырастает более чем в 700 строк. После чего регулярное выражение просто ничего не находит.

**Тут есть момент**, например, если поставить вместо тега «section» тег «div», все будет работать.

**Другие изыскания:**

Пробовал реализацию через **PHPDocument**, но там возникли проблемы с кодировкой (штука в том, что я не знаю в какой кодировке будет использован разрабатываемый скрипт).

Пробовал, сначала найти:

```
<section name="myname1"> ... </section>
```

, а потом через функцию «preg_match_all» с флагом «PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE» найти количество открывающихся и закрывающихся одноименных тегов и их позиции в строке, с последующим вычислением конечного закрывающего тега для искомого. Но и тут я споткнулся об пресловутую кириллицу.

Пробовал **XPath**, не могу добиться чтобы он корректно переваривал не до конца валидную верстку. Особенно сильно ругается на использование svg инлайном. В завершении бросает критическую ошибку: 
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'

Библиотека «**Simple HTML DOM Parser**» и ей подобные, строят свою логику на использовании PHPDocument, XPath. Следовательно имеют те же болячки с переработкой невалидного HTML

Есть, у кого-то идеи как можно решить этот вопрос? Хотя бы идя какого-нибудь алгоритма.

---

[Вот еще ссылка на подобный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/15133/223041), но проблемы остаются. Приведенное регулярное выражение не будет работать для следующего шаблона:

```
<table>
   ...
   <table></table>
   ...
</table>
```

Но будет для этого:

```
<table>
   ...
   <table>Обязательно текст или пробел</table>
   ...
</table>
```

Такой баг легко поправим, однако этот пример так же откажет в поиске конструкции с большой вложенностью, если во вложенности не использован тег искомого элемента DOM — это уже тема моего поста.

Может кто сможет скорректировать и оптимизировать приведенный пример?

Comment: Распарсить регуляркой - это всегда возможно (видел где-то статью с формальным доказательством этого) и всегда очень больно. Разве что модификатор `x` чуть поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема решена:**

```
/<table\b[^\>]*\bname=(\"|')?table01\1[^\>]*>(?>([^\<]+|<(?!\/?table\b))|(<table[^\>]*>(?:(?2)|(?3)|)+?<\/table>))*<\/table>/ix
```

https://regex101.com/r/EzXAfL/1

Название тега: table, можно заменить на ([a-z0-9]+), тогда будет выполнен поиск по всем тегам. Главное потом подставить эту группу в соответствующие позиции в регулярном выражении.

Название и значение атрибута («name», «table01»), можно подставлять динамически (в моем случае задаются переменными php)

Все описанные мной проблемы с парсингом вложенности большого объема — решены.

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь окажусь полезным :)

Comment: [А если кавычек не будет?](https://regex101.com/r/4ZlZwf/1)

Comment: Вы забыли поставить необязательность для закрывающей кавычки:
<table\b[^\>]*\bname=(\"|')?table01\1?[^\>]*>(?>([^\<]+|<(?!\/?table\b))|(<table[^\>]*>(?:(?2)|(?3)|)+?<\/table>))*<\/table>

Comment: Регулярку можно подкорректировать исходя из того, на сколько не валидный код вы ожидаете получить. 

Какие-то вопиющие случаи она естественно учесть не сможет. Но например такие подходы:
`<     div ... > ... <    /  
 div>` — Можно решить установкой необязательного пробельного символа «\s*»

Comment: Ага, оказалось не вы, а я забыл :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень хорошая библиотека, Simple HTML DOM Parser: https://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/
Предлагаю посмотреть как реализован там разбор на теги и получение содержимого и применить у себя.

Регулярное выражения не самый лучший инструмент для парсинга html.

Comment: а там как рас помойму регулярки и юзают :) а вообще какой нибудь пример для полноты ответа добавьте

Comment: По воду использования регулярных выражений для парсинга HTML согласен, не самый удачный выбор инструмента. Но я вынужден искать решение в этом направлении, т.к стандартные модули PHP (PHPDocument, XPath) для корректной работы требуют на входе валидную структуру DOM. В моем случае, это непозволительная роскошь (у библиотеки Simple HTML DOM Parser та же болячка, так как основана на вышеупомянутых модулях).  

Но брезжит луч надежды, особенно после прочтения статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/171667/.